# What is considered a large .mo / .po file?

Tags: optimization, internationalization, gettext

We're in the middle of migrating our database-stored message keys to a `gettext()` mechanism. Our projects has several subprojects and because we wanted efficient queries when we used to pull messages from the database messages was grouped by these subprojects, so we always queried the actual group only.

Now i'm wondering should we separate these different subprojects into different domains given the fact we shouldn't worry about database queries now?

Sample sizes for subprojects:

```
domain1.po    200k
domain2.po    67k
domain3.po    20k
```

Should we split these files or everything will be fine if they will be merged together?

What is considered a large (inefficient) .mo/.po file in terms of speed/memory consumption?